# Checkbox won't check using on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make checkbox check upon clicking on container's span, but the problem is that when I click on the span it checks/unchecks but when I click on the checkbox itself it doesn't work, any idea why?

```js
$("#cus_date").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$('.cus_date').on('click',function(){
    if($("#cus_date").is(":checked")) {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", true)
    }
});
```

```css
.cus_date {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-addon cus_date" for="filtre_periode_custom"><input type="checkbox" id="cus_date" name="filtre_periode_custom" value="1"></span>
```

[Fiddle version here](https://jsfiddle.net/695avqcs/4/)

Comment: You prevent the default action on your jquery code

Comment: The idea was to prevent the default action so the span click would take it's place, but apparently my reasoning was false. Thanks!

Comment: Prevent default is fine, it's the `e.stopPropagation` that's stopping the click event bubbling up to the span.  If you're just using the click event to change the checkbox, then no real difference (as the various working answers show) - but if the span-click does something *else* then it's an important distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation` on  clicking the checkbox. Simply add the `id` of the checkbox as part of the selector:

```js
$('.cus_date, #cus_date').on('click',function(){
    if($("#cus_date").is(":checked")) {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", true)
    }
});
```

```css
.cus_date {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-addon cus_date" for="filtre_periode_custom"><input type="checkbox" id="cus_date" name="filtre_periode_custom" value="1"></span>
```

Comment: @Elshobokshy, this works because the event is attached to both `span` and `checkbox`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as answered as you both solved my problem and you have less rep than he does.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#cus_date").on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault() 
     e.stopPropagation()
});
$('.cus_date').on('click',function(){
    if($("#cus_date").is(":checked")) {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", true)
    }
});
```

```css
.cus_date {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-addon cus_date" for="filtre_periode_custom"><input type="checkbox" id="cus_date" name="filtre_periode_custom" value="1"></span>
```

`preventDefault` will stop default action and `stopPropagation` will stop trigger parent's `onClick` event

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you prevent the default action (preventDefault)
Stopping the event propagation is enough

```js
$("#cus_date").on('click', function(e) {
  
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$('.cus_date').on('click',function(){
    if($("#cus_date").is(":checked")) {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $("#cus_date").prop("checked", true)
    }
});
```

```css
.cus_date {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-addon cus_date" for="filtre_periode_custom"><input type="checkbox" id="cus_date" name="filtre_periode_custom" value="1"></span>
```

---

Anyway instead of using a span element you could wrap the checkbox in a `label` element so you could avoid to use javascript at all.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxPNGm)

Comment: Thank you sir :) The span is used for a different purpose not mentioned here that's why I'm using it, but thank you for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
$('.cus_date, #cus_date').on('click', function() {
  $('#cus_date').prop('checked', !$('#cus_date').is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.cus_date {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<span class="input-group-addon cus_date" for="filtre_periode_custom">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cus_date" name="filtre_periode_custom" value="1">
</span>
```

Comment: Nice logic ! :D